# How to prevent lag when changing button title and color?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to have a button change title and color every second but there is lag. What happens is that when it changes from lets say YELLOW to RED the button will show R.. or simply ... for a split second. It does not happen every time the button changes, only a few times. This the the code I have.

```
@IBOutlet var tapButton: UIButton!

var color:[UIColor] = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.yellowColor(), UIColor.greenColor()]

var colorName:[String] = ["RED", "BLUE", "YELLOW", "GREEN"]

func game(){
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(SecondViewController.subtractTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func subtractTime(){
    seconds -= 1

    let num1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(4))
    let num2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(4))

    tapButton.titleLabel?.textColor = color[num1]
    tapButton.setTitle(colorName[num2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    game()
}
```

Comment: This code looks fine.  Do you have some other code that is running on the main thread and hogging the CPU?  This code will only run when the main thread is available, so if you have long running code elsewhere on the main thread, the updates will be delayed.

Comment: You should not keep a reference to NSTimer, but it seems that you are and maybe your creating two timers (just a thought).

Comment: I am using single view controller and have multiple view controllers and each have their own viewcontroller.swift file.

Comment: I would suggest using the CPU instrument to profile your app and figure out where it is spending time during the title/color change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the segues to Show Details, this seems to have fixed my problem. I also have the timers stop when I change view controllers.

I no longer get the lag that I was experiencing before.